# How would I convert this code into a for loop for PYTHON

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

```
B = 3
while(B <= 11):
  print(B)
  B = B+2
```

I already tried a bunch of stuff, all of it crap, like:

```
for B <= 11:
```

which is apparently invalid syntax, and i've tried:

```
B= 3
if B <= 11:
   print(B)
   B = B+2
```

which does absolutely nothing

So, any suggestions?

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/For_with_a_specified_step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're learning Python. What you are looking for is a [range](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function):

```
for B in range(3,12,2):
    print(B)
```

Note that the parameters here are 3, 12 and 2.

- The 3 is the starting point.
- The 12 is used instead of 11 for the end of the range, because the `range()` function in Python excludes the last value of the range. You'll want to keep that in mind when writing Python code.
- The 2 is the step value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (Java):

```
for(int B = 3; B <= 11; B += 2)
{
    System.out.println(B);
}
```